# Iterate values in columns so that the sum for each row equals, or is close to, a given value

Tags: excel

Using Excel I am trying to sort out several columns of values such that the sum of their rows equals a certain value, in this case `45`. A sum value between `40` and `45` would suffice.

I have several columns next to each other. Each column is about ten cells going down. Each of the cells contains a number ranging from `5` to `12`. The sum of each row now equals values ranging from `20` to `70`. I want the sum of each row to equal about `45`.

How would I set it up so that the values in the columns arrange themselves in this manner?

Comment: This is a really difficult question to answer since we are dealing with such a huge number of potential combinations to find the combination that satisfies the requirements that each row sum to a number between 40 and 45. If you have 4 columns, and 10 rows in each column, then the number of potential combinations is (10!)^4 which is astronomically huge. Obviously quite a few of those combinations will solve your problem. How many columns do you have?

Comment: In addition, can you guarantee that it is possible to create rows which all add up to a relatively small range of sum (40 - 45 does not give a lot of wiggle room). Your data set would have to be carefully created to make sure that such a thing is even possible. How many columns do you have and how many rows? What is the global sum of your sum column?

Comment: This is a version of the "knapsack" or "backpack" problem which can be solved with the Solver.  It is a standard example in a number of optimization or business methods texts.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem